# page won't show up in codeigniter made website

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Hello I am pretty new to codeIgniter and I've created a contact page with controller and a view.. the only problem is that I don't get anything when I go to the link http://www.mydomain.nl/index.php/contact

My controller is as follows

```
    <?php 
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['title'] = 'Contact';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Naam', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('beschrijving', 'Beschrijving', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email')

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('contact/index');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('contact/formsucces');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

with this controller i've also created a folder in my view called contact
in this folder i've got 2 files the index.php and a formsucces.php for when the form is beeing submitted.

My question is what am i doing wrong? i've looked all the examples I could find but nothing helps..

edit: added more code

This is a controller for the news section. the controller and the view is the same as the contact controller and view.

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

and to be really really sure that my directory, paths etc are correct here is the print screen of my directory

[image]

Comment: your code is just fine. check up the path to your views to make sure nothing wrong. or add more related code to be debugged.

Comment: i have added more code :) and the directory tree

Comment: if you are ready to try :). I just think that you have to change the index view name to something else. just a thought.

Comment: sorry, didn't had time to test it.. I did now but no result it still says didn't found 404 error

Comment: try specifying .php extension explicitly when you call your view.

Comment: I tried but still nothing, I even created a test controller doesn't work either..

Comment: do you have htaccess file you can post here to see?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.bellataxihaarlem.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bellataxihaarlem.nl/index.php/home$1 [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Comment: I'm not sure that there's something wrong with your htaccess

Comment: i dont thinkso because the htaccess I don't have locally only on my host.. so it should work :( i became desperatee

Comment: enter codeigniter chat room to continue our discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22686/discussion-between-reshad-and-mamdouh-alramadan)